# How to return Lucene highlighter results through a Cypher query?

Tags: lucene, neo4j, cypher

I have a 2.1.5 Neo4J database on which I created a node_auto_index to perform fulltext search on several node properties.

As such, a query like the following:

`START n=node:node_auto_index("title:Boa*") RETURN n;`

works like a charm.

However, I would like to know if this is possible, somehow, to make a cypher query return the results of the Lucene highlighter so I can properly highlight the results of a fuzzy search to my users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so, no.   To use the [Lucene Highlighter](http://hrycan.com/2009/10/25/lucene-highlighter-howto/) requires that you use the Lucene API directly to annotate the results with the bit that matched against the index.

What Cypher returns basically boils down to primitive types, e.g. you can return strings, integers, dates, etc.  The more complex types that come back as a result of cypher queries are things like nodes, paths, relationships.

To return a highlighted result, you'd either need markup, or the context of some other UI (like Swing) to show the result that you want.

If you really want this, I think you'd probably need to use the Java API and [interact with  lucene index objects directly](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-lucene-extras.html).  This would allow you to get as far as knowing what the highlight *should be* via the Lucene API.  How you would then present that would be entirely dependent on your app (whether web, Swing, whatever)

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. I'll give the Java API a try then. I guess I'll have to write a server plugin to do so? Or does a Cypher extension remain possible in such a case?

Comment: It's hard to say.  It depends on how your UI works, but this sounds to me like something that would be better suited to a java application.  A cypher extension may be possible, but I'm afraid it would require many extension points (in the return types, and also in the query clauses).

Comment: Thanks again. I'll try a server plugin. My UI is web and a REST route should fit my needs perfectly. I am just trying to avoid needing a Solr/Elastic Search database along my Neo4j one for a really basic fuzzy search.